# QT QStandardItemModel segfaulting

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm pretty new to QT, and I'm trying to take a list from a text file and output it into QT with nice formatting.

I managed to get the list printed on the window, but it has to be able to be sorted.

I have the radio buttons set up right now so that one of them displays the list and the other clears the list.

The problem is that when I switch from the list to the cleared list back to the list the program segfaults and I don't understand why.

The files are here.

**winelist.cpp**

```
#include "winelist.h"
#include "ui_winelist.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

wineList::wineList(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::wineList)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->ratingButton->setChecked(true);

    fillList();
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Wine Name")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Vintage")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Rating")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, new QStandardItem(QString("Price")));

    ui->listOutput->setModel(model);
}

wineList::~wineList()
{
    delete ui;
}

void wineList::on_sortButton_clicked()
{
    if( ui->ratingButton->isChecked())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            model->setItem(i,0,wList[i].wineName);
            model->setItem(i,1,wList[i].vintage);
            model->setItem(i,2,wList[i].rating);
            model->setItem(i,3,wList[i].price);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                model->setItem(i, j, new QStandardItem(QString("")));
            }
        }
    }

    ui->listOutput->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->listOutput->resizeRowsToContents();
}

void wineList::fillList()
{

    Wine wine;
    QString line;
    QStringList lineElements;

    QFile wineText(":/winelist.txt");
    if (wineText.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        while ((line = line.fromUtf8(wineText.readLine())) != "")
        {
            lineElements = line.split(";");

            lineElements[0].replace("\t", "");
            lineElements[1].replace("\t", "");

            wine.wineName = new QStandardItem(QString(lineElements.at(0)));
            wine.vintage =  new QStandardItem(QString(lineElements.at(1)));
            wine.rating =   new QStandardItem(QString::number(lineElements.at(2).toInt()));
            wine.price =    new QStandardItem(QString::number(lineElements.at(3).toInt()));

            wList.append(wine);
        }
    }
    wineText.close();
}
```

**winelist.h**

```
#ifndef WINELIST_H
#define WINELIST_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

namespace Ui {
class wineList;
}

struct Wine {
    QStandardItem* wineName;
    QStandardItem* vintage;
    QStandardItem* rating;
    QStandardItem* price;
};

class wineList : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit wineList(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~wineList();

private slots:
    void on_sortButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::wineList *ui;

    QVarLengthArray<Wine> wList;
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(100, 4, this);

    void fillList();
    void printList(QStandardItemModel *model);
};

#endif // WINELIST_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "winelist.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    wineList w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[Clicking sort the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfWlH.jpg)

[Switching Radio Button and clicking sort again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XReH.jpg)

[Switching Radio Button back and clicking sort again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AneD1.jpg)

Any Help is appreciated, I am completely lost here.

Comment: Have you debugged your program?

Comment: Yeah. It tells me I have a segfault and from there I'm not sure where to go. 3rd picture.

Comment: I'm guessing `wList` isn't as big as you think it is.

Comment: I have a version of this that prints directly to the command line and it works perfectly. It was only when I tried recreate it in QT that i ran into issues. I didn't actually change very much of the code. I'm just having issues with printing the contents into a table.

Comment: @djscrew You step through your program line by line _before_ it segfaults to figure out which line is causing the segfault. Then look at the values of your variables to figure out what your program is doing wrong. Learning to debug is part and parcel of learning to program.

Comment: I'm having issues debugging it because I'm not entirely sure what to look for. I'm not very familiar with the QT framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `on_sortButton_clicked` you're trying to read data from a list, but not doing any range checks. Instead, you've hardcoded 100 there.
You should rewrite this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    model->setItem(i,0,wList[i].wineName);
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wList.size(); i++) {
        model->setItem(i,0,wList[i].wineName);
```

--upd---

When you initially populate your model, it takes ownership over items from `wList`. When you replace model items with empty ones, it deletes initial items from `wList`. After this your `wList` is no move valid, because it contains `Wine` structs with dangling pointers. That's why when you try to populate your model second time, it crashes.

Comment: After trying this, nothing changed.

Comment: I Checked in the debugger and sure enough wList was full of dangling pointers. Thanks for helping out, Everything is now working as planned.